# RED5 Error: netconnection.connect.failed

Tags: http, server, red5

I have installed RED5 server on the server with static IP of server and port 80.

```
http://server_ip:80
```

Server is running, no problem.
But when I am trying to Install a ready-made application

```
http://server_ip/installer
```

I am getting..

```
Error: netconnection.connect.failed
```

Answer (score 0):

A flash var must be supplied to the installer swf, or it will default to [localhost as seen here](https://github.com/Red5/red5-flash/blob/master/installer/src/functions.as#L23).